# UITestControlNotAvailableException: The control is not available or not valid

Tags: .net, automated-tests, coded-ui-tests

I have written such code:

```
int timeOut = 300000; //milliseconds
string _displayTextProp = "DisplayText";

WpfText screenResult = MainWindow.UITableStatusControlCustom.ScreenResultLabelValue;

screenResult.WaitForControlExist(timeOut);
screenResult.WaitForControlPropertyNotEqual(_displayTextProp, null, timeOut);
screenResult.WaitForControlPropertyNotEqual(_displayTextProp, "0", timeOut);// (1)
```

**In this (1) method I have gotten exception UITestControlNotAvailableException**

Test method  threw exception: 
Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITest.Extension.UITestControlNotAvailableException: The control is not available or not valid. ---> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: Exception from HRESULT: 0x80042002
              at System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ThrowExceptionForHRInternal(Int32 errorCode, IntPtr errorInfo)
   at System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ThrowExceptionForHR(Int32 errorCode)
   at MS.Internal.Automation.UiaCoreApi.CheckError(Int32 hr)
   at MS.Internal.Automation.UiaCoreApi.UiaGetPropertyValue(SafeNodeHandle hnode, Int32 propertyId, Object& value)
   at System.Windows.Automation.AutomationElement.GetCurrentPropertyValue(AutomationProperty property, Boolean ignoreDefaultValue)
   at System.Windows.Automation.AutomationElement.GetCurrentPropertyValue(AutomationProperty property)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITest.Extension.Uia.UiaUtility.GetAutomationPropertyValue[T](AutomationElement element, AutomationProperty property)
 --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITest.Extension.Uia.UiaUtility.MapAndThrowException(SystemException e, IUITechnologyElement element)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITest.Extension.Uia.UiaUtility.GetAutomationPropertyValue[T](AutomationElement element, AutomationProperty property)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITest.Extension.Uia.UiaElement.GetAutomationPropertyValue[T](AutomationProperty automationProperty)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITest.Extension.Uia.UiaElement.GetRequestedState(AccessibleStates requestedState)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITest.Extension.UITechnologyElement.IsState(IUITechnologyElement element, AccessibleStates state)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting.UITestControl.EnsureValid(Boolean waitForReady, Boolean refetch)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting.UITestControl.GetPropertyValue(String propertyName)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting.UITestControl.GetProperty(String propertyName)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting.UITestControl.<>c_*DisplayClass4.<WaitForControlPropertyNotEqual>b*_3(UITestControl ctrl)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting.UITestControl.WaitForCondition[T](T conditionContext, Predicate`1 conditionEvaluator, Int32 millisecondsTimeout)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting.UITestControl.WaitForControlCondition(Predicate`1 conditionEvaluator, Int32 millisecondsTimeout)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting.UITestControl.WaitForControlPropertyNotEqual(String propertyName, Object propertyValue, Int32 millisecondsTimeout)

**What is reason can be such behaviour?**

Thank you for advance!

Answer (score 2):

As per [this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.uitest.extension.uitestcontrolnotavailableexception.aspx):

This exception is thrown when the UI test framework attempts to access a UI element that is no longer available or cannot be accessed.  So you may have disposed of an item, or not have access to the element any longer and are now trying to access it.  Potentially you've failed to initialize one of the AutomationElements?

Comment: Thanks Mark. "So you may have disposed of an item, or not have access to the element any longer and are now trying to access it" What way can I  use to resolve this?

Comment: You need to look at the objects you've created - make sure you've created them when you try to access them.  If it helps, put some checks in first to see if the objects have been initialized and are != null.

Comment: Thank Mark. In my case I have added    screenResult.SearchConfigurations.Add(SearchConfiguration.AlwaysSearch);

Comment: So in this case my control is not cached and the playback always find it.And this is help me.

Comment: @Mark Mayo, in my case I cannot run the same recorded test (which involves WPF, etc.) twice. I get the exact same error. I am trying to understand what is going on, but the link you have provided is not exactly verbose. So, what can I do? How can I change the Search configuration for an already recorded test? Thanks.

Comment: Actually, I think I found what my problem was - I bastardized UIMap and made it static. That broke a bunch of stuff.